# Excel VBA RemoveDuplicates Array from NamedTable

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, regional-settings

I've created the following macro with record-macro (so at that time it worked) however if I try to re-use it it fails with:

> error code 1004

```
Application.Goto Reference:="table101"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("table101[#Alle]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array( _
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), Header:=xlYes
```

The table has between 300-2000 columns. The code fails at the last line.

I've already searched multiple possible solutions but couldn't work out any of them.

Comment: How many columns are there in `table101`? On which line does it fail?

Comment: between 300-2000. it fails at

ActiveSheet.Range("table101[#Alle]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array( _
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), Header:=xlYes

Comment: change `"table101[#Alle]"` to `"table101"`. You can also remove the first two lines and write directly: `Range("table101").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), Header:=xlYes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Application.Goto Reference:="table101"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("table101[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array( _
                            1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

The change is `Alle` to `All`. Which is **strange** and sounds like a **bug**, because with the macro-recorder produces `[#Alle]` and the recorded code  does not work:

[image]

It works, if I remove the `e` though. This is the first time I see recorded code in MS Excel not working.

Comment: it seams the record macro took the German-Version (UI) while the VBA Version needed the English. Simple and stupid. Thanks, that worked!

Comment: @Matt - welcome. Still, usually the recorded code works quite ok, there are enough settings to mimic the language specific UI. If you have time & desire, file a bug report at Excel.